# tail inject line number of log?

Tags: fluentd

From `a.log`

```
log-line1
logline2
```

I want to add the line number in fluentd.conf

like

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /*
  refresh_interval 1
  pos_file /tmp/access.log.pos
  line_num @line
</source>
```

and the output of the source will be

```
{log:log-line1,line_num:0}
{log:logline2,line_num:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add the line number with in_tail plugin.
Because in_tail plugin does not have such functionality.